# AngularJS parent controller is not invoking while going back from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have **`AngluarJS`** view with listing of some items, user can `delete/update` each item by clicking on it. When user click one line item we are showing a `child view`. When user do some delete/update action on the line item I am re-loading the parent view using `state.go` function.

But my parent view controller is not getting called( statements in parent controller is not getting invoked).

I have used `$urlRouterProvider`to manage each state. 
I am going back to parent state by using following statement:

```
$state.go('parent',{}, {reload: true});
```

Above action is triggering my configuration snippet, and loading new data from server, following is the code snippet in configuration to load parent state:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
            url                 : '/parent',
            templateUrl         :  'app/parent.html',
            controller          :  'ParentController',
            controllerAs        :  'parentController',
            resolve         : {
                list : function($stateParams, parentServices){
                    return parentServices.getList();
                }

            }
        });
```

`parentServices.getList()` this function is getting invoked. I have put break point for the first statement in the parent controller, but its not getting invoked.

While reloading the page its loading fine. Please let me know what's wrong with the current flow, which is blocking from calling controller.

#### Update : State configruations

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
            url                 : '/parent',
            templateUrl         :  'app/parent-management/parent.html',
            controller          :  'ParentController',
            controllerAs        :  'parentController',
            resolve         : {
                parentList : function($stateParams, keyServices){
                    return parentServices.getList();
                }

            }
        });
        $stateProvider.state('parent.child', {
            url             : '/:action/:id',
            templateUrl     : 'app/parent-management/parent-child.html',
            controller      : 'ParentChildController',
            controllerAs    : 'parentChildController',
            resolve         : {
                currentModelID : function($stateParams){
                    return {
                        id      : $stateParams.id,
                        action  : $stateParams.action
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

> If I navigate to a child state the child controller will be
>   initialised, if I then navigate back to the parent state, the parent
>   controller will not be re-created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place your list of items inside an Angular service you can then use this service to access the data in both your parent and child controllers. Make the service responsible for updating (make sure you update and don't replace) the list with information from the server.

You can then use this information in both your controllers and any manipulation each controller makes on the data will be available to both controllers without the need to re-initialise the controller (which won't happen for the parent controller when using nested states).

Comment: Yes I can provide more informations. All items are stored in DB. From my service I am making an rest api calls to do CURD operations.

Child view will be updating the data in DB using service. So after some updates happens I would like to re-render the updated data informations in parent view. So from child view I am calling a state.go('parent').

Comment: In some case user may delete item from child view so I need to re-load the parent view with new list of items (of same page size).

Comment: If you navigate to a new state using `$state.go()`, there's no need to explicitly do anything if the controller loads the list items on initialisation. The controller isn't active in the background, it's created when you change to the state it's used for.

The only time I could imagine you needing to get the parent to update is if the parent controller has the child controller in a nested view. Even then, using a service, both views can look at the same list and manipulate it.

Comment: I am  going back to parent view using `state.go()`. As you mentioned I am using a common service for parent and view to get the updated data.
One doubt now, when ever we go to a state, where we went previously, *controller will start executing* right? 

in my case when I come back to parent view, ant statements in controller is not executing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L68452vk/1/

What I've observed is if you're in a state and try to navigate to the same state using `$state.go()` nothing will happen. If you navigate to a child state the child controller will be initialised, if you then navigate back to the parent state, the parent controller will not be re-created. This could well be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Are you using nested states?

Comment: As you said : **If you navigate to a child state the child controller will be initialised, if you then navigate back to the parent state, the parent controller will not be re-created** this is my scenario.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you, using services in the way I describe will remove the need to reload the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the structure is the most important part in Angular apps and router play a vital role in this.

```
        $stateProvider
            .state("versions-layout", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/versions/:id",
                templateUrl: "js/versions/versions-layout.html",
                controller: "VersionsController",
                controllerAs: "versionsVm",
                resolve: {
                    version: ["$stateParams", "VersionsService", function ($stateParams, VersionsService) {
                        return VersionsService.getVersionById($stateParams.id);
                    }]
                },
            })
            .state('versions', {
                parent: "versions-layout",
                url: "",
                views: {
                    "version-characteristics": {
                        templateUrl: 'js/versions/version-characteristics/version-characteristics.html',
                        controller: 'VersionCharacteristicsController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    },
                    "programs": {
                        templateUrl: 'js/versions/programs/programs.html',
                        controller: 'ProgramsController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                        resolve: {
                            programsData: ["version", function (version) {
                                return version.data.programs;
                            }]
                        }
                    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem by doing the following changes in my code:

My `child view` was inside a `modal popup`, so to go back to `parent view` from `child view` (with reloading of data), the code snippet was written as follows:

```
$state.go(states.parent,{}, {reload: true});
closeChilUIPopover();// functionality to close the modal popup of child
```

When I commented out **`closeChilUIPopover()`** function, parent view was rendering fine with newly loaded data.

So then I changed order of call as follows:

```
closeChilUIPopover();
$state.go(states.parent,{}, {reload: true});
```

But after changing the order of call also had same issue. So I have added the **`closeChildUIPopover`** in **`callback`** function of **`$state.go`** as follows:

```
$state.go(states.parent,{}, {reload: true}).then(function(){
    closeChilUIPopover();
});
```

Now everything is working fine.
Thanks for all help.